# url in href mix localhost with domain name

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart2.x

My web build with opencart the product link add domain name link to localhost inside href in anchor tag like in the code show

```
<div class="product-image-wrap">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="/" title="Oyster Platters" alt="Oyster Platters">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/https://thewebname.com/index.php?option=com_mijoshop&amp;route=product/category&amp;path=49">
            <div class="item-content animate">
                <p>Discover<img alt="arrow" src="/images/icones/arrow-white.png"></p>
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

my .htaccess is clean also I searched everywhere in the database to where the links the links are socked correct : `index.php?option=com_mijoshop&amp;route=product/category&amp;path=49`

if I put that link in address bar in any browser

```
http://127.0.0.1/index.php?option=com_mijoshop&lang=en&order_id=6954&order_product_id=10879&route=account/order/reorder&Itemid=221
```

it will convert to

```
http://127.0.0.1/https://thewebname.com/index.php?option=com_mijoshop&route=product/category&path=49
```

I'm not using any SEO.

it's happen only for products not for all the web

Comment: I’d start by checking the template that outputs these wrong link URLs …

Comment: I did it's opencart It's take the url of the second store and add it to url I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Most welcome to here

please check your both config.php file. http and https set up correctly

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://127.0.0.1/');
// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://127.0.0.1/');
```

**i think my answer very hlepful for you. if you are appriciate with me. you can mark answer.**

Thank you

Comment: Still having that problem; nothing changed

Comment: you can debug code on product controller and check it.

Comment: I did the url var_dump($data['href']) return "http://127.0.0.1/https://thewebname.com/index.php?option=com_mijoshop&amp;route=product/category&amp;path=49"

Comment: you can use str_replace("/https://thewebname.com",""); i think it's very help ful. try this

Comment: send me your email-id please.

Comment: alaemz@yandex.com my email. `Opencart It's take the url of the second store and add it to url I don't know why`

Comment: see my email and reply to me.